# Why does jfrog maven artifactory plugin is invoked at validation phase?

Tags: java, maven, repository, maven-plugin, artifactory

[Here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin) is a jfrom artifactory plugin overview. They told:

> The plugin's invocation phase is "validate" by default and we recommend you don't change it so the plugin is called as early as possible in the lifecycle of your Maven build.

As I understant (am I wrong?) this plugin is used to deploy maven projects. So this plugin should "wait" until all test are passed, sources compiled and package and deploy artifact only at delploy phase, no?

**Question**: Why is it linked to validate phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the `artifactory-maven-plugin` applies a different pattern than usual mojo (Maven goal) implementations: it relies on [Maven Lifecycle listeners/extensions](https://maven.apache.org/examples/maven-3-lifecycle-extensions.html).

Looking at its [github repository](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info), the mojo actually:

- Makes sure to skip the `maven-deploy-plugin` [default binding](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html) by [setting](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/blob/master/build-info-extractor-maven3-plugin/src/main/groovy/org/jfrog/build/extractor/maven/plugin/PublishMojo.groovy#L130) the [`maven.deploy.skip`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#skip) property to `true`
- adds a custom Maven listener to the build session, the `BuildInfoRecorderLifecycleParticipant`
- Then at the right moment effectively [deploys](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/blob/04409ac12f0b9575a827dcbdc556800016e7a609/build-info-extractor-maven3/src/main/java/org/jfrog/build/extractor/maven/BuildInfoRecorder.java#L170) via its plugin.

The binding to the `validate` phase is necessary to effectively skip the default `deploy` behavior and register its own listeners.

Comment: That's a 100% right answer. The reason we did it is to deploy all the modules of a multi-project build at once, preventing failing build to deploy partial results.

Comment: Hi @JBaruch, is it possible to skip deployment / to configure deployment (like maven-deploy-plugin deploy-file goal) for some of the modules of a multi-module-project?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked inside the [source code](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/blob/master/build-info-extractor-maven3-plugin/src/main/groovy/org/jfrog/build/extractor/maven/plugin/PublishMojo.groovy) of the plugin and found this line:

```
String deployGoals = 'deploy,maven-deploy-plugin'
```

This field is used in the `recordBuildInfo` method. This method registers the class [`BuildInfoRecorder`](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/blob/3dc5922b219473ea580e44843c0dd4126cf712ef/build-info-extractor-maven3/src/main/java/org/jfrog/build/extractor/maven/BuildInfoRecorder.java) as listener which [calls](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/blob/3dc5922b219473ea580e44843c0dd4126cf712ef/build-info-extractor-maven3/src/main/java/org/jfrog/build/extractor/maven/BuildInfoRecorder.java#L174) the real [`deploy`](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/blob/master/build-info-extractor-maven3/src/main/java/org/jfrog/build/extractor/maven/BuildDeploymentHelper.java#L58) method when the [session ends](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/blob/master/build-info-extractor-maven3/src/main/java/org/jfrog/build/extractor/maven/BuildInfoRecorder.java#L168).